# Ant Design React : Vertical align div inside a col

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, vertical-alignment

I'm using Ant Design for a React project. It seems quite good and easy to use, except for one thing : vertical alignment. I'm trying to vertical align those 2 blocks of text on the right inside their grey parent div but cant make it work.

[image]

If I use foundation 6 it works perfectly but with ant cant figure it out what's wrong. So here is my code :

```
 <Row className="keynumbers" align="middle">
          <Col span={12}>
            <Graph tickets={nature} />
          </Col>
          <Col span={12} align='middle'>
          <Space
              direction="vertical"
              size="middle"
              style={{
                display: 'flex',
              }}
            >
            <TotalTickets total={total} />
              <TimeSolving
                tickets={resolution}
              />
              </Space>
          </Col>
        </Row>
```

The components TimeSolving and TotalTickets are basic div :

TotalTickets

```
<div class="block" >
   <h3>{volumeTickets}</h3>
   <p>nombre de tickets</p>
</div>
```

TimeSolving

```
<div class="block"> 
  <h3>{prop.tickets}</h3>
  <p>temps moyen de résolution</p>
</div>
```

and the css for .block

```
 .block{
background: #f8f8f8;
height: 140px;
}
```

I just want to vertical align those two blocks of text.

Did I miss something ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding css for your `block` class, you can use flexbox to vertically centre its contents

```css
.block {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[image: Edit nice-varahamihira-11lin0]

## Edit:

You could achieve similar with Ant's `Space` primitive, which is really just a Flexbox primitive.

```
const TimeSolving = () => (
  <Space
    direction="vertical"
    size={0}
    style={{
      height: 140,
      justifyContent: "center"
    }}
  >
    <h3>10</h3>
    <p>temps moyen de résolution</p>
  </Space>
);
```

[image: Edit shy-hooks-m4jtxw]

Comment: thanks a lot, it works! It's weird that ant design does'nt provide a simple class to do that. For example, on Foundation 6, you can use align-middle class, with grid-x class and it does the trick perfectly. Anyway, thank you

Comment: @ArthurFortin I've updated my answer. It's weird that that Space api has an `align` property but does not have a `justification` property. As such, you still need to use css to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set `<Col />`'s `span` as `{24}`? Because [Ant Design uses 24 grid](https://ant.design/docs/spec/layout).

```
<Row className="keynumbers" align="middle">
    <Col span={24}>
        <Graph tickets={nature} />
    </Col>
    <Col span={24} align='middle'>
        <Space direction="vertical" size="middle" style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <TotalTickets total={total} />
            <TimeSolving tickets={resolution} />
        </Space>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem.